# Best approach for dynamic Laravel/Ajax image voting page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am writing an application for  a image voting contest. I am a newbie for this kind of ajax based dynamic pages. I have questions about how to make it correctly and as this is my first try, I need answers for some performance based questions. I can add votes but , I cant get the total votes for the images. Hence my mind is confused about performance because all the users can vote at the same time. How can I show total vote count for every image. my db table is below in the second question.

I added a vote button for every image :

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini upvote newsbutton" id="{{ $contestimage->id }}">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
  <div id="voteresponse"></div>
```

and sending form to a route by using ajax :

```
$('.upvote').click( function(event) {

          event.preventDefault();

          $("#voteresponse").html('');
            var voteID = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
              url: "voteimage",
              type: "post",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {id : voteID},
              success: function(data, textStatus){
                if(data.success == 'true'){
                  $('#voteresponse').html(data.message);
                  return true;
                }else{
                  $('#voteresponse').popover({
                    title: 'Hata!',
                    content: data.message 
                  });
                }
              },
              error:function(){
                  $('#voteresponse').popover({
                    title: 'error!',
                    content: 'Server error' 
                  });
              }
            }); 
          });
```

and my controller action is

```
   public function postVote($id = null)
    {    
        if (Sentry::check()) {

            if (Request::ajax())
            {

                $id=Input::get('contestImageId');
                $image = ContestImage::find($id);

                $vote = "1";
                $user = Sentry::getUser()->id;

                // Grab the vote if it already exists.
                $entry = Vote::where('user_id', $user)->where('contest_id', $image)->first();

                if (!empty($entry))
                {
                    $entry->vote = $vote;
                    $entry->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    $entry = new Vote;
                    $entry->user_id = $user;
                    $entry->contest_id = $image->id;
                    $entry->vote ="1";
                    $entry->save();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Not an AJAX request.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "User not logged in.";
        }
    }
```

Code works but I am stuck at this point.I cant figure how to send back total vote count and as all other ajax pages how can I add a script to refresh votecount when anyother user voted ?Does this make any performance problems?

Second question is related with first question: I created my vote migration and collecting in the db

```
user_id(int)
contestimage_id(int)
vote(tinyinteger to use as 1)
```

I have a belongsTo and hasMany relationship between votes and contestimages and I want to get total count using `$contestimage->votes()->count();` is this a nice option to calculate the votes?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function where you count the number of votes, check out 'Raw Expressions ' on [this](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) page, that should help you out. You can use MySql `count(*)` to count the number of rows.

With that function, display the amount of votes on your page, and then have it return the total number of votes after you succesfully run the postVote function..

```
$entry = new Vote;
$entry->user_id = $user;
$entry->contest_id = $image->id;
$entry->vote ="1";
$entry->save();
// RETURN NUMBER OF VOTES HERE
```

Then have the number that gets returned update the div containing your total vote count

```
if(data.success == 'true'){
$('#voteresponse').html(data.message);
$('#totalvotes').html(data.totalvotes);
return true;
```